# Column not found in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-4, self-join

I'm trying to create a self join in laravel using aliases, but it doesn't seem to want to pick it up, because I get an error saying that the columns `p1.sub_menu` and `p2.5` are not found. Here is my join:

```
$menu = DB::table('pages AS p1')
         ->leftJoin('pages AS p2', 'p1.sub_menu', '=', 'p2.'.$id.'')->get();
```

Comment: Obviously you don't have `pages.5` field, do you? It's `p2.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Error because of your leftJoin statement

Params in leftJoin statement are columns which you want to use relationships.

```
$menu = DB::table('pages AS p1')->leftJoin('pages AS p2', 'p1.sub_menu', '=', **'p2.'.$id.''**)->get();
```

My solution is:

```
$menu = DB::table('pages AS p1')->leftJoin('pages AS p2', 'p1.sub_menu', '=', 'p2.sub_menu')->where("p2.menu_id", "=", $menu_id)->get();
```

Comment: It says that p2.id is an unknown column, but there is an id column

Comment: You can use `<?php var_dump(DB::getQuerylog()?>` to view mySQL query to debug. I don't know your db structure so my query can be wrong

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but the var_dump(DB::getQuerylog() would be after the join statement?

Comment: yes. remember `die()` after that to see what you need